# Focus Trapped Inside TextView With LinkMovementMethod When Navigating With Arrow Keys

Tags: android, android-edittext, linkmovementmethod

I have a TextView with the `LinkMovementMethod` movement method. I have also called `Linkify.addLinks(description view, Linkify.ALL)` to make links clickable. The issue I am seeing is on Oreo devices (Android 8.0). When navigating the page with hardware arrow keys, when the focus shifts to the TextView, the arrow keys will scroll the content of the TextView but the focus is trapped in the view. Once the view has scrolled to the top/bottom, pressing the up/down arrow cannot get focus out the view. How can I get the EditText to give up focus when the view has fully scrolled with arrow keys?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am running into the same issue.